# How to get text in png file using Java

Tags: java, testing, png

I want to check if particular string is present in the image. Is that possible? Is [pngj](http://code.google.com/p/pngj/) can do that?

My file will contain a graph and some legends. I want to check the if the legends are correct.

Comment: What you're looking for is OCR software. The `pngj` library does not mention it can do OCR.

Comment: PNGJ can't to that. You need a library for text recognition.

Comment: This is definitely not trivial. The general process is known as OCR (optical character recognition) which reads the text. However, it's far from perfect and might pick up stuff which isn't text, and if there's any more text in your graph (labels on axes etc), they will be read as well.

Comment: You are looking for OCR (Optical character recognition : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition ). you should look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971344/java-based-ocr-sdk-api

Comment: Thanks Pratik and dvhh. tesseract may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do that with pngj. The text that is visible in the PNG image is not internally stored as text. You will need [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) software if you wish to identify the text.

However it would be *much* better if you could get the data in another format that is easier to parse by a computer.

Comment: @Rajasankar: Something like a CSV file or an XML file would be a lot easier to parse than a PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be possible. However, you should find a good OCR library. And then, assuming that your OCR library returned proper results you need to verify somehow if your legends are placed in proper positions.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use scala to give out my solution. If you are java developer, it is quite easy for you to convert the scala code to your java code.

Step1: in **build.sbt** to add one more line

```
libraryDependencies += "com.asprise.ocr" % "java-ocr-api" % "[15,)"
```

Step2: **import** library

```
import com.asprise.ocr.Ocr
```

Step2: scala code.Please note: here  is a **File** type. If you only have fileName/filePath, you need to use **new File()** to convert it.

```
try {
      // Image
      Ocr.setUp()
      val ocr = new Ocr
      ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST)
      val files = List(<your_file>)
      val outputString = ocr.recognize(files.toArray, Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT)
      ocr.stopEngine()
      Some(outputString)
} catch {
      case e: Exception => None // todo: to support multiple file types
}
```

I also write a blog to give more details info about [how to extract text/content from another file(pdf, html, image, etc)](https://lihaimei.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/text-extraction-from-url-by-scala/)

If you want to read more about this java-ocr-api, you can read [its official website here](https://asprise.com/ocr/docs/html/asprise-ocr-api-java.html#recognizes-text-only-or-barcode-only).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Asprise OCR](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/index.php?lang=java) out.  It's a good OCR API available in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tesserat.sample code below:-

```
String src = "path of File";
String ocrString = "";
Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();         instance.setDatapath("path of tessdata\\Tess4J\\tessdata");
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(src));
ocrString = instance.doOCR(new File(src));
```