# How to get the text from dynamically changing the text in gif image using java for selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gif

[image: http://www.smartfocus.com/sites/default/files/personalize_based_on_4.gif]

Need to get all the text from this gif file and then need to verify some text.

Comment: Selenium is not working with OCR [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition ]. You need to apply OCR script for get data inside the image. You can search on google for image automation.

Comment: <section class="paragraph-one-column-section" style="background-image: url(http://www.smartfocus.com/sites/default/files/styles/carousel_large/public/pink_bg.png?itok=yMI9TNkV);">
<div class="container">
<div class="field-name-field-column-1">
<p>
<img class="media-element file-default" width="1200" height="400" alt="" src="http://www.smartfocus.com/sites/default/files/personalize_based_on_4.gif"/>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>

Comment: Refer my above comment

Comment: Above is the html tags. I was unable to run the code using OCR library which are posted in this website itself. Need a way to get the text from GIF image.

Comment: Selenium can get the image but it is not working with Inside of any image

Comment: Correct, but this need to be handled using java and get all the text from the image. So can you please tell me how to get the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could I verify text in image using Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660424/could-i-verify-text-in-image-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not allow to do it or can say this functionality is not added in Selenium.

Selenium can only work with HTML DOM. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488194/how-to-get-text-in-png-file-using-java)

Use OCR for this. OCR convert image to text. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)

Refer this link for Basic java program.

[OCR Program](http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2013/10/extract-and-verify-text-from-image.html)

Above solution might be helpful to you.

Comment: OCR converts only static images and not animated GIF image. I tried using OCR for this application and its not working.

Comment: I am not so much expert in OCR programs. You can ask different question for this.